# DBObject to java object conversion

Tags: mongodb-java

I am using morphia template for mongo operations but for some reason I need to use java driver to get the records from mongo db.
I am trying to find records from mongo db using java driver and then converting to java object.
For this I am first converting DBObject to Json and and then converting json to Java object.
But while converting from json to java object all fields are mapped except the objectid is changed.
my json looks likes this

```
{"
    _id":{
        "$oid":"5222e5c41abdbdfe6439c358"
    },
    .... more fields
}
```

after converson to java object this object id is different and thats causing problem. 
Is there any other way for this kind of mapping?

Thanks.

In my POJO class I am using ObjectId type for id.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using Morphia's [fromObject()](https://rawgit.com/wiki/mongodb/morphia/javadoc/0.108/apidocs/org/mongodb/morphia/Morphia.html#fromDBObject%28java.lang.Class,%20com.mongodb.DBObject%29) method?

Comment: No because for some reason I need to use java driver instead of Morphia template